# No <wsse:Security> element in TerminateSequence message

Tags: soap, ws-security, gsoap, ws-reliablemessaging

I am implementing a soap client using the `gsoap` library with `WS-Reliable Messaging` and `WS-Security` to call a one-way remote action.

All the soap messages (`CreateSequence`, actual message, `CloseSequence`) have a `<wsse:Security>` element in the soap header except the `TerminateSequence` packet.
Am I missing something?

My code(SSCCE) looks like this:

```
// load plugins
soap_register_plugin(soap, soap_wsa);
soap_register_plugin(soap, soap_wsrm);
soap_register_plugin(soap, soap_wsse);

// set security
soap_wsse_add_Security(soap);
soap_wsse_add_Security_actor(soap, "recipient");
soap_wsse_add_UsernameTokenText(soap, NULL, "username", "password"); //plain text

// start sequence
soap_wsrm_create(soap, "http://localhost:4242/", NULL, 0, NULL, &seq);

// set wsrm header
soap_wsrm_request(soap, seq, NULL, "http://some/action/here/");

// call remote action
some_remote_method(param);

// close sequence
soap_wsrm_close(soap, seq, NULL);

// terminate sequence
soap_wsrm_terminate(soap, seq, NULL);

//clean up soap object here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs due to a [bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/gsoap2/bugs/967/) in the wsrm plugin of gsoap library v2.8.15. The fix is available in v2.8.18